# Running compiled C++ code with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have been working my way through Dirk Eddelbuettel's `Rcpp` tutorial here:

http://www.rinfinance.com/agenda/

I have learned how to save a C++ file in a directory and call it and run it from within R.  The C++ file I am running is called 'logabs2.ccp' and its contents are directly from one of Dirk's slides:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

inline double f(double x) { return ::log(::fabs(x)); }

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> logabs2(std::vector<double> x) {
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), f);
    return x;
}
```

I run it with this R code:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("c:/users/mmiller21/simple r programs/logabs2.cpp")
logabs2(seq(-5, 5, by=2))
# [1] 1.609438 1.098612 0.000000 0.000000 1.098612 1.609438
```

I am running the code on a Windows 7 machine from within the R GUI that seems to install by default.  I also installed the most recent version of `Rtools`. The above R code seems to take a relatively long time to run.  I suspect most of that time is devoted to compiling the C++ code and that once the C++ code is compiled it runs very quickly.  `Microbenchmark` certainly suggests that `Rcpp` reduces computation time.

I have never used C++ until now, but I know that when I compile C code I get an *.exe file.  I have searched my hard-drive from a file called `logabs2.exe` but cannot find one.  I am wondering whether the above C++ code might run even faster if a `logabs2.exe` file was created.  Is it possible to create a `logabs2.exe` file and store it in a folder somewhere and then have Rcpp call that file whenever I wanted to use it?  I do not know whether that makes sense.  If I could store a C++ function in an *.exe file then perhaps I would not have to compile the function every time I wanted to use it with Rcpp and then perhaps the Rcpp code would be even faster.

Sorry if this question does not make sense or is a duplicate.  If it is possible to store the C++ function as an *.exe file I am hoping someone will show me how to modify my R code above to run it.  Thank you for any help with this or for setting me straight on why what I suggest is not possible or recommended.

I look forward to seeing Dirk's new book.

Comment: Have you looked at the command `R CMD SHLIB`? With that you can just compile your C++ function to a dll file and then load the compiled file with `dyn.load()`. Have a look at `?SHLIB` and `?dyn.load` for details!

Comment: @user1981275 Thank you for the comment.  So far I have gotten to this point: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64>rcmd SHLIB -o c:\users\mmiller21\documents\r\win-library\3.0\rcpp\include\logabs2.dll c:\users\mmiller21\documents\r\win-library\3.0\rcpp\include\logabs2.cpp   I get the following message: make: *** No rule to make target 'c:\users\mmiller21\documents\r\win-library\3.0\rcpp\include\logabs2.o', needed by 'c:\users\mmiller21\documents\r\win-library\3.0\rcpp\include\logabs2.dll'.  Stop. The message seems to be saying I am missing an object file, familiar to me from my work with C.

Comment: I am using the DOS command window.  If the problem really is a missing object file can you suggest how I can create an object file?  Perhaps once it is created it would go in a list along with logabs2.cpp at the end of the command in the previous comment?  Thank you regardless.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you to user1981275, Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois for their responses.  Below is how I compiled a C++ file and created a *.dll, then called and used that *.dll file inside `R`.

Step 1.  I created a new folder called 'c:\users\mmiller21\myrpackages' and pasted the file 'logabs2.cpp' into that new folder.  The file 'logabs2.cpp' was created as described in my original post.

Step 2.  Inside the new folder I created a new `R` package called 'logabs2' using an `R` file I wrote called 'new package creation.r'.  The contents of 'new package creation.r' are:

```
setwd('c:/users/mmiller21/myrpackages/')

library(Rcpp)

Rcpp.package.skeleton("logabs2", example_code = FALSE, cpp_files = c("logabs2.cpp"))
```

I found the above syntax for `Rcpp.package.skeleton` on one of Hadley Wickham's websites:  https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Rcpp

Step 3.  I installed the new `R` package "logabs2" in `R` using the following line in the DOS command window:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64>R CMD INSTALL -l c:\users\mmiller21\documents\r\win-library\3.0\ c:\users\mmiller21\myrpackages\logabs2
```

where:

the location of the rcmd.exe file is:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64>
```

the location of installed `R` packages on my computer is:

```
c:\users\mmiller21\documents\r\win-library\3.0\
```

and the location of my new `R` package prior to being installed is:

```
c:\users\mmiller21\myrpackages\
```

Syntax used in the DOS command window was found by trial and error and may not be ideal.  At some point I pasted a copy of 'logabs2.cpp' in 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64>' but I do not think that mattered.

Step 4.  After installing the new `R` package I ran it using an `R` file I named 'new package usage.r' in the 'c:/users/mmiller21/myrpackages/' folder (although I do not think the folder was important).  The contents of 'new package usage.r' are:

```
library(logabs2)
logabs2(seq(-5, 5, by=2))
```

The output was:

```
# [1] 1.609438 1.098612 0.000000 0.000000 1.098612 1.609438
```

This file loaded the package `Rcpp` without me asking.

In this case base `R` was faster assuming I did this correctly.

```
#> microbenchmark(logabs2(seq(-5, 5, by=2)), times = 100)
#Unit: microseconds
#                        expr    min     lq  median     uq     max neval
# logabs2(seq(-5, 5, by = 2)) 43.086 44.453 50.6075 69.756 190.803   100

#> microbenchmark(log(abs(seq(-5, 5, by=2))), times=100)
#Unit: microseconds
#                         expr    min     lq median    uq     max neval
# log(abs(seq(-5, 5, by = 2))) 38.298 38.982 39.666 40.35 173.023   100
```

However, using the dll file was faster than calling the external cpp file:

```
system.time(

cppFunction("
NumericVector logabs(NumericVector x) {
    return log(abs(x));
}
")

)

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.06    0.08    5.85
```

Although base R seems faster or as fast as the *.dll file in this case, I have no doubt that using the *.dll file with `Rcpp` will be faster than base `R` in most cases.

This was my first attempt creating an R package or using Rcpp and no doubt I did not use the most efficient methods.  Also, I apologize for any typographic errors in this post.

EDIT

In a comment below I think Romain Francois suggested I modify the *.cpp file to the following:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector logabs(NumericVector x) {
return log(abs(x));
}
```

and recreate my `R` package, which I have now done.  I then compared base `R` against my new package using the following code:

```
library(logabs)

logabs(seq(-5, 5, by=2))
log(abs(seq(-5, 5, by=2)))

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(logabs(seq(-5, 5, by=2)), log(abs(seq(-5, 5, by=2))), times = 100000)
```

Base `R` is still a tiny bit faster or no different:

```
Unit: microseconds
                         expr    min     lq median     uq       max neval
   logabs(seq(-5, 5, by = 2)) 42.401 45.137 46.505 69.073 39754.598 1e+05
 log(abs(seq(-5, 5, by = 2))) 37.614 40.350 41.718 62.234  3422.133 1e+05
```

Perhaps this is because base `R` is already vectorized.  I suspect with more complex functions base `R` will be much slower.  Or perhaps I am still not using the most efficient approach, or perhaps I simply made an error somewhere.

Comment: Using `std::vector<double>` or a `NumericVector` is not the same thing. `lobabs2` first has to convert the R object it gets to a `std::vector<double>`, this is expensive as you need to copy the data. Then at the end you return a `std::vector<double>`, so `Rcpp` needs to transform this to an R object, again this means data copy.

Comment: In your last code block, you are measuring the time it takes to compile the code. This is just not a fair comparison.

Comment: @Romain Francois  Thank you for your comments.  I am not trying to be unfair.  I simply have not yet learned enough to provide a more efficient answer.  I have not yet been able to get dyn.load and .Call to work, for example, after creating the *.dll file with Rcpp.package.skeleton and/or installing the new package.  Nor have I yet been able to create the *.dll file using SHLIB.  If I arrive at a more efficient solution I will post it.  My goal is to learn how to maximize the utility of Rcpp.

Comment: Don't worry about `dyn.load` and `.Call`. Just use the package you apparently have succeeded in creating. But perhaps instead of having `logabs2` which for some reason use `std::vector<double>`, just use `logabs` which is probably much more efficient since it does not have to make data copies. The way to keep pre compiled C++ functions is to make a package.

Answer (score 5):

You say

> I have never used C++ until now, but I know that when I compile C code
>   I get an *.exe file

and that is true if and only you build an *executable*.  Here, we build *dynamically loadable libraries* and those thend to have different extensionos depending on the operating system: .dll for Windoze, .so for Linux, .dynlib for OS X.

So nothing wrong here, you simply had the wrong assumption.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get some entity you can keep, what you are looking for is an `R` package. There are many resources online to learn how to make them (e.g. [Hadley's slides](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41902/easy-packages3.pdf)).

We have `Rcpp.package.skeleton` you might find useful.

So, the function is compiled once when the package is installed, and then you just use it.