# Java RCaller reuse a function

Tags: java, performance, compilation, rcpp, rcaller

I'm using RCaller in order to execute a R file in Java.

Basically, it looks like this:

```
RCaller caller = new RCaller();
RCode code = new RCode();
caller.setRscriptExecutable(PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE);
caller.cleanRCode();

code.R_source(PATH_TO_FILE);
code.addRCode("result<-test('" + param + "')");

caller.setRCode(code);
caller.runAndReturnResult("result");
```

... my problem is that I'm using `Rcpp` in this R file (`PATH_TO_FILE`) and it takes several seconds to compile this external C++ file in R. Therefore I want to reuse the function and not to compile this file all the time when I execute `.runAndReturnResult(...)`.

The R file looks like this:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("/cppTest.cpp")

myfunc<- test(param)
{

    t<-cppTest(4) 
    return(t)
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this using `RCaller` or any other suggestions in case of other libraries which are capable of this?

Help is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see this as a Rcpp problem.  It works as designed -- your deployment within Java may hamper you.

Reuse of R code is commonly achieved by creating a package which reliably allows you to store and reload object code. That is (among other things) what a package is for.

You essentially ask for a reinvention of `sourceCpp()` to also give you the benefits of a package.  That won't happen.  Please use a package.

And with that this then has nothing to do with the embedding inside a Java app.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Could you please explain me what you mean with `use a package`? I'm just the java developer who got a R script... :-/ Some further hints or links? Thank you so much!

Comment: Got it.. I guess... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149295/running-compiled-c-code-with-rcpp Thank you! :)